# include <sstream> not working in Xcode 9.2

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, stream

I'm learning c++ now and have encountered an issue trying to concatenate strings and numbers because `sstream` is not working for me.

The errors I got are:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_string, std::__1::allocator >' and 'int').

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name = "Jane";
    int age = 28;

    string info = "Name: " + name + "; age:" + age;
    cout >> info >> endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with sstream - you cannot concatenate arbitrary types like this `string info = "Name: " + name + "; age:" + age;` in C++. Nothing is sstream allows you to do that.

Comment: Can you show the code where string streams are not working? `string info = "Name: " + name + "; age:" + age;` will never work.

Comment: @VictorGubin this question doesn't seem to be splitting a string at all...can you expand on why you think it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue isn't with `sstream`, it's with this line right here:

```
string info = "Name: " + name + "; age:" + age;
```

Everything looks all well and good until `"; age:" + age`. You cannot add a `string` and an `int`. You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the `int` to a `string`:

```
string info = "Name: " + name + "; age:" + to_string(age);
```

`to_string` was added in C++11, but if for whatever reason you can't use C++11, you can define this function yourself using stringstreams:

```
template <typename T>
string to_string(const T &thing) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << thing;
    return oss.str();
}
```

---

Also note that you're using the extraction operator on `cout`. You probably meant this:

```
cout << info << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a stringstream to create a new string that concatenates strings and other types you would need something like this:

```
 int meaning = 42;
 ostringstream os;
 os << "The meaning of life is " << meaning;
 string s = os.str();
```